# Android : Non-Crashing App

Tags: android, error-handling, stability

I know this could be a very ambiguous question But I need some help. I'm working for a project which consists of users doing some tests in Tablets. the tests they do are always the same but sometimes the app crashes for certain Tablets/users. As I mentioned, the tests are the same for every person and the tablets too. However, in some cases the app stops working. I have looked for some Warning errors ( intent receiver leaked , etc) but I think I have resolved them. I think this could be a matter of memory problems (mp3, images are in the tests).

Is there a way of testing this app's stability? I must mention that these crashes only happen when there are some users doing this in the same Wi-Fi and the same SERVER. Could be a server problem?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you made a good verification on what you get from the server, there is no reason this cause the app crash, On the other hand if you always do the same test suite, I recommend you to use an android test framework like [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/). Finally do you have logs on the error that cause the application crash?

Comment: Hi , I have no logs because when the user do their test, the Tablets are not connected to the PC. but what I say is that if do myself the test , there are no crashes. I'll check Robotium

Comment: If there are lots of images, try to make sure they are pre-resized according to the tablets resolution, and also make sure you are freeing resources once the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, they are preiszed, I will loke more info about freeing resources in Android. Are there any useful links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) or something similar - I have found it to be VERY useful in the past.

It will send a crash report for you, providing the stack trace.

(yes, there are plenty of others that may be better / worse / different / the same etc... I'm just mentioning this one because it is the one I had experience with)

Comment: Thank you Richard, I will try that alongside Traceview.